# Fade In/Out HTML Video Audio Using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

Im trying to fade in & out the audio of my HTML video. My code fades in and plays a new video on loop whenever a new entry is added into my database, when another entry is added the old video fades out and the new one fades in. I've been trying to use the .volume function to fade in and out the audio of the videos, but i've had no luck getting it to work. Does anyone know whats wrong with my code or if there is an alternative way to achieve this? Cheers.

HTML

```
 <div id="blocker"></div>
 <video autoplay poster="" id="bgvid" loop="loop" src="0.mp4" style="width: 100%;"></video>
```

JQUERY

```
    $('#blocker').fadeOut(1000);

    var checkForChanges = function () {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "assets/php/videoprocess.php",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {

                var videonum = (data["VIDEOID"]); // NEW VIDEO ID
                var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1); // URL ID
                var vid = document.getElementById("bgvid"); // VIDEO DIV
                document.getElementById("bgvid").volume = 0;   // Set video volume ????

                window.location.hash = '#' + videonum;
                window.onhashchange = function () {

                    if (videonum == hash) { }

                    else {

                        vid.pause();
                        vid.animate({ volume: 0 }, 800 );  // Volume fade ????

                            $('#blocker').fadeIn(1000,  // VIDEO FADE

                            function(){

                                vid.src = location.hash.slice(1) + '.mp4';  // CHANGE VIDEO SRC
                                vid.setAttribute('loop','loop');
                                vid.load();
                                vid.play();
                                vid.animate({ volume: 1 }, 800 ); // Volume fade ????
                                $('#blocker').fadeOut(1000); // VIDEO FADE

                            });
                    }
                }

            }

        });


        setTimeout(checkForChanges, 1000);
    };
    checkForChanges();
```